# RequireJs won't load script by name

Tags: javascript, html

I've just started to learn about RequireJs but am unable to load a js dependency using it's custom shortened name. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here, I try to load the knockout js library using only "knockout" but it throws an error

```
Error: Script error for "knockout"
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

if I use "knockout-3.4.0" it works fine but I'd prefer to use the shortened

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" data-main="js/init.js" src="js/require.js"></script>
 </head>
    <body>
        <h1 data-bind="text: TabIndx">Hello World</h1>  
  <script>
  require(['knockout', 'viewModel'], function(ko, viewModel) {
   var vm = new viewModel();
   ko.applyBindings(vm);
  });
  </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
require.config({
 baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        knockout: 'knockout-3.4.0',
  viewModel: 'viewModel'
    }
});
```

Comment: Is `init.js` where you are defining `require.config`? Could you post the whole contents of `init.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is because RequireJS hasn't fully loaded itself and its custom configuration before you're requesting local paths. What you should *really* be doing if you're using RequireJS is having a module responsible for creating the view model and applying the bindings like in your example.

```
// app.js
define(['knockout', 'viewModel'], function (ko, viewModel) {
    var vm = new viewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});

require.config({
    baseUrl: './js/',
    paths: {
        knockout: 'knockout-3.4.0',
        viewModel: 'viewModel',
        app: 'app'
    }
});
```

I'm not sure how init.js looks, but here I have made it a little module responsible for launching the app.js file.

```
define(['app'], function (app) {
    app.init();
});
```

Your config should ideally be refactored into its own file, where `require-config.js` just contains your config snippet, like so: -

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="js/init.js" src="js/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/require-config.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand now, I had my config code inside init.js but it is async loaded and was not loaded in time hence the error message.